# How to get maximal dates period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query witch providing me the results, some thing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   contractId INT  NOT NULL 
  ,recordId   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,amount     NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
  ,amountType INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,date       datetime NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3248627,1444.00,266,'2008-02-27 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3248627,471.78,49622,'2008-02-27 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3321672,244.00,266,'2008-03-13 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3321672,0.00,49622,'2008-03-13 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3414133,765.00,266,'2008-04-11 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3414133,251.81,49622,'2008-04-11 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3555690,0.00,266,'2008-07-02 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,3555690,0.00,49622,'2008-07-02 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4229093,382.63,266,'2008-11-04 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4229093,28.51,49622,'2008-11-04 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4259641,382.63,266,'2008-11-05 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4259641,28.51,49622,'2008-11-05 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4291553,382.63,266,'2008-11-06 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4291553,28.51,49622,'2008-11-06 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4450231,5071.63,266,'2009-08-18 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO t1 (contractId,recordId,amount,amountType,date) VALUES (1,4450231,1201.67,49622,'2009-08-18 00:00:00.000');
```

Here we could see that we have two period with overdue amounts. The next query will represent it:

```
select  
  * 
  , (case when (SUM(amount) over(partition by contractId, recordId)) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [isOverdue]
from
  t1
```

You can try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c909ac/2/0)

So, I need to get the greatest period of overdue. Some thing like this:

| contractId | dateSatrt | dateEnd | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008-02-27 00:00:00.000 | 2008-04-11 00:00:00.000 | datediff... |
| 1 | 2008-11-04 00:00:00.000 | 2009-08-18 00:00:00.000 | datediff... |

From here i can get what i need easily.

This is my second attempt to get what I need. Here is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703095/query-of-dates-periods). Here I am trying to be more clearly and accurate.
Please, don't judge me too hard if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you are counting where your calculated sum is greater than `0`.

You can define the islands by the count of the rows that are `0` (these are the same for the non-`0` values).  This looks like:

```
select contractid, min(date), max(date), datediff(day, min(date), max(date)) as days_diff
from (select t1.*, sum(1 - isOverdue) over (partition by contractId order by date) as island
      from (select t1.*,
                   (case when (SUM(amount) over(partition by contractId, recordId)) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as isOverdue
            from t1
           ) t1
     ) t1
where isOverdue = 1
group by contractid, island;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16a5b0885d821228aa949f1249471a43) is a db<>fiddle.